# How to Access Single Item in JSON Encoded Associated Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have an array in php which looks like

```
 $allData = [
             {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5},
             {'a' => 45, 'b' => 23, 'c' => 88, 'd' => 33, 'e' => 82},
             {'a' => 100, 'b' => 75, 'c' => 12, 'd' => 7, 'e' => 19}
           ]

echo json_encode($allData);
```

now in client side I have

```
request.done(function(data) {
      console.log(data); 
      console.log (data[0][0]);  
});
```

the `console.log(data);` is working fine and printing out  `[Object, Object]` with details but the `console.log (data[0][0]);` is returning `undefined`. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Comment: You have an array of objects ... so `data[0].a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an array of objects, try doing this in javascript:

```
request.done(function(data) {
      console.log(data); 
      console.log(data[0]);
      console.log(data[0].a);  
});
```

Comment: Thanks Divij but I really confused here so I am not getting JSON?

Comment: It is JSON nonetheless. Valid JSON can contain anything be it objects, arrays, strings and numbers. Associated array becomes an object while a standard array defined using `[1, 2]` becomes a nested array.

Comment: just one final question, so what is the JSON String?

Comment: I still need 5 minutes to accept you answer Sir ;-)

Comment: If you want the `data[0][0]` to work, in PHP change the associative array into a list and you'll be set. You will lose the properties `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.

Comment: yeah but I always got confused the diff between JSON Object, Array, and String

Comment: Think of JSON as simply a format to exchange data over a network request. Since it is used to exchange data, it can take on different values depending on what needs to be exchanged. As a result, arrays, strings and objects, all are valid JSON formats. You are sending a list of objects from the server which is exactly how it is translated on the server side. You can also send a list of lists (data[0][0]), a list of strings(data[0], data[1]) or just a string itself.

Comment: Technically, you are not getting JSON. The server is encoding a data structure to JSON, and the client is decoding the JSON text to a data structure. What you are actually "getting" in the done call is a plain ol' javascript object